# Message returned with history ().list () cannot be found with messages ().get () in GMail

Tags: python, gmail-api

I am fetching a list of changed messages using the gmail-api ([`history.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list)) in Python and need to retrieve a message for which I have not previously received the content. However, when using the [`message.get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) method on the received message id I get an 404 Not found error. How can this happen and what can be done to fix it?

I get the same results testing using the API docs interface, and the message is not listed as deleted or removed (and I can see it in the GMail interface).

Comment: This might be a spam or draft message, I know they are not returned by `message.list()` (by default), but what about `message.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your scenario, for a draft message the message ID is like temporary, where it is replaced when it is already sent. But when it is SENT, it's id is somehow unified , you can use it to get message in INBOX or other LABELS in your gmail. If you get a 404 message on `message.get()` it might be a mail created from Draft and was already sent. I found a [issue - Link to draft](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/issues/370), it stated that "if you were to then go and edit or update that draft, that
message id request would 404, but the draft id request would return the
updated resource with it's new message and thread ids."

Comment: Thanks, in this case no drafts were involved. Probably spam.